# Add npm install script in package.json file?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "install": "npm install"         //Creates a loop and tries to run `npm install` continuously.
  },
```

I would like to have this script so that I can just just click on the icon/option in my IDE as shown below instead of executing `npm install` in the terminal to install packages.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the `install` script to something else, like `setup`.